# How to know when dll events fired

Tags: c#, events, dll

I created a dll contain this event handler:

```
public void tcp1_Data(object sender, Sockets.DataEventArgs e)
{
  Tcp tcp = (Tcp)sender;

  response = "Socket Connection" + tcp.Tag.ToString() + " replied : " + e.Data.ToString();

  tcp.Close();
}
```

this will fire when server write some thing in socket connection. so by this, I can read the data on socket.

I used this dll in another project. I want to know in my project (that used dll) exactly when server is writing data on socket connection. as you see in tcp1_Data event, I set result into response variable and in main project (that used dll), I checked this variable polling (if response is not null, it means that this event fired). but Its not what I want. I dont want check this variable all the time.

is there any other way?

---

I tried this as @ThorstenDittmar said:

my dll project (its name is ClientSample) contain:

1. `TheClassInDLL Class`

   ```
   public class TheClassInDLL
   {

       public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> DataEventCalled;

       public void tcp1_Data(object sender, Sockets.DataEventArgs e)
       {
           Tcp tcp = (Tcp)sender;

           // Note: LOCAL variable
           string myresponse = "Socket Connection" + tcp.Tag.ToString() + " replied : " + e.Data.ToString();

           // Call the new event here
           if (DataEventCalled != null)
               DataEventCalled(this, new MyEventArgs(myresponse));

           tcp.Close();
       }

       // We use this class to pass arguments to the event handler
       public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
       {
           public MyEventArgs(string response)
           {
               this.Response = response;
           }

           public string Response
           {
               get;
               private set;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   1. `TCPSample class`

   public class TCPSample
   {
     Tcp tcp = new Tcp();
     tcp.Data += new System.EventHandler

   and in another project that I used above dll:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       private TheClassInDLL myClass;
       ClientSample.TCPSample t = new ClientSample.TCPSample();

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           myClass = new TheClassInDLL();
           myClass.DataEventCalled += DataEvent;
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           t.newTCP();
       }

       private void DataEvent(object sender, TheClassInDLL.MyEventArgs e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Response);
       }

   }
   ```

but It didnt work, DataEvent never happend.
Thanks for any helping...

Comment: I don't see an event, just an event handler. And think I didn't completely understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Alireza I want to know exactly when this event handler execute in my project... Its simple but I dont know how to explain...

Comment: You just got an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you wrote here is an event handler that is called when something happens. There must be a class containing this event handler. Instead of writing a global response variable, declare and invoke another event you can subscribe to from outside that class like this:

```
public class <TheClassInDLL>
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> DataEventCalled;

    // SNIP: All the other code that leads to tcp1_Data being called
    ...

    // The event handler that's called by some code in the class
    public void tcp1_Data(object sender, Dart.Sockets.DataEventArgs e)
    {
        Tcp tcp = (Tcp)sender;

        // Note: LOCAL variable
        string myresponse = "Socket Connection" + tcp.Tag.ToString() + " replied : " + e.Data.ToString();

        // Call the new event here
        if (DataEventCalled != null)
            DataEventCalled(this, new MyEventArgs(myresponse));

        tcp.Close();
    }

    // We use this class to pass arguments to the event handler
    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public MyEventArgs(string response)
        {
            this.Response = response;
        }

        public string Response
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```

From the caller, you use it like this:

```
public class <TheCallingClassOutsideDLL>
{
    private <TheClassInDLL> myClass;

    public TheCallingClassOutsideDLL()
    {
        myClass = new TheClassInDLL();
        myClass.DataEventCalled += DataEvent;
    }

    private void DataEvent(object sender, <TheClassInDLL>.MyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Response);
    }
}
```

**Of course you need to replace `<TheClassInDLL>` and `<TheCallingClassOutsideDLL>` with the real class names! Creating additional classes of course doesn't work!**

Comment: I used your code but it didnt work. I edit my question and write new code as u helped.

Comment: OK, I'm speaking in *examples* here. Of course you don't create a class named `TheClassInDLL`! You extend the class that contains the code you already have with the new event (I suppose that class is named `TCPSample`, but it's hard to guess from your code?), the event args class and so on! I'll change my answer to make this clearer...

Comment: I had a bad mistake. thanks a lot for your perfect answer. It worked :) :)

Answer (score 0):

For that you got to define your own event and raise it when needed...
for Example -> In  the class where you set the "response" variable define an event

```
//your custom event
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> MyCustomEvent;

//This will raise your event and notify all who registered
private void RaiseMyCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = MyCustomEvent;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Maybe you will also need CustomEventArgs (used in the example above)

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public String Message {get;private set;}
    public CustomEventArgs(String message){
        this.Message = message;
    }

}
```

The class which is using the dll and that wants to get notified needs to register for this event

```
YourDllClassInstance.MyCustomEvent += OnMyCustomEvent;

public void OnMyCustomEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e){
    Console.WriteLine("Event received");
}
```

That means in your dll class you got to do something like the following when you want to raise the event

```
response = "blablabla";
RaiseMyCustomEvent(new CustomEventArgs(response);
```

Is that what you where asking for?